# in vuejs styling ag-grid's cell data

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

what  am  I doing is combine some key value pairs and bold the value in that pair and put it in ag-grid rowData ,
my problem is bold() method adds the  tag to that value it is not getting bold[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your problem related to [tag:django] ?

Comment: no its related javascript ,vuejs,ag-grid

Comment: So... which framework/library is it? Please tag the correct one.

Comment: i am using vuejs framework and ag-grid-vue package for table